# Создание jar файла с комментариями кода

Tags: java

Я написал свою маленькою библиотеку, все методы и переменние коментировал.

Когда я скомпилировал jar, подключил его к проекту, и декомпилил, все комментарии пропали.

Как создать jar с комментариями? Про генерацию javadoc знаю, нужно именно комментарии.

Comment: В maven принято делать отдельный .sources.jar  и приличные ide это знают и показывают исходники корректно

Comment: [maven-source-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/)

Comment: Никак. Все комментарии игнорируются (что правильно. Зачем они нужны в конечном компилированном продукте?)

Comment: Но взять тот же класс HashMap, все коменты видно

Comment: Комментарии надо писать с помощью аннотаций

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сборке проекта Maven есть специальный плагин, который собирает javadoc  во время сборки нужно добавить в  pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
...
       <!--
            Maven Javadoc Plugin
            Javadocs provide documentation that makes it easier for developers to know
            how to use a particular class. Instead of reading and understanding the
            actual source code, the developer can use the Javadocs instead to lookup
            the class attributes and methods.
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

используем плагин при сборке проекта

```
<build>
   ...
   <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
   </plugins>
</build>
```

добавляем раздел

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</reporting>
```

это создаст jar-файл с документацией. Дальше Maven надо указать загружать зависимости с документацией, в Идеи в идеи это выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аналогичный плагин есть для сборки архива с кодом maven-source-plugin.
Подробнее смотри в [документации Maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/).

Comment: Спасибо, виручил